# Is there a way to filter pandas dataframe by number of item in ordered category?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I have a pandas dataframe with an inconvenient ordered category field, I might even not know what category values are, I just know it's ordered and there are three values in the category:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'C1': pd.Categorical(list('abbacabac'), categories=['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=True), 'C2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
```

I can get, say, all the items that are in the second category by doing:

```
df1 = dfs[dfs.C1 == 'b']
```

But I might not even know what the categories are, or they might be really inconvenient ones to type in or something.
Considering the categories in the example are ordered, is there a simple way to just get the items that have the second category by order, something like

```
df1 = dfs[dfs.C1.category_order == 1]
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cat.categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html) and select by indexing:

```
dfs = dfs[dfs.C1 == dfs.C1.cat.categories[1]]
print (dfs)
  C1  C2
1  b   2
2  b   3
6  b   7
```